# How to refer OLD.X at ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET X = OLD.X + EXCLUDED.X

Tags: postgresql, upsert

There are an alias for "old value" in the  `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`?

---

My real life problem is

```
INSERT INTO art.validterm (namespace,term,X,info)
    SELECT namespace,term,array_agg(Xi), 'etc'
    FROM term_raw_Xs
    GROUP BY namespace,term
ON CONFLICT (term) DO 
    UPDATE SET aliases=OLD.X||EXCLUDED.X 
    WHERE term=EXCLUDED.term
```

PS:  no "OLD" exists, is the question. The parser say that only X is ambigous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply replacing `OLD` with the name of the table, in your case: `validterm`, worked for me.

My test:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS work.term_raw;

CREATE TABLE work.term_raw
(
unique_field INT UNIQUE,
x_field TEXT
);

INSERT INTO work.term_raw VALUES (1, 'A');

INSERT INTO work.term_raw VALUES (1, 'B')
ON CONFLICT (unique_field) DO UPDATE SET x_field = term_raw.x_field || EXCLUDED.x_field;

SELECT * FROM work.term_raw;
```

My result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  correct (!). Another (tested) solution is to use an alias, `... INSERT INTO work.term_raw AS tt VALUES (...) ... SET x_field = tt.x_field || ...`.

Comment: @klin - I'm not sure I follow - I did not specify a `WHERE` clause in my answer.

Comment: @Nicarus- but Peter did.